# Restricting movement of box2d body along an axis in andEngine

Tags: box2d, andengine, accelerometer, game-physics

Purpose is to restrict the movement of a box2d physics body in a certain axis - to move either horizontally or vertically, Here is the body definition :

```
Body ballBody;
Sprite ball;    
ball = new AnimatedSprite(x_end, y_end-ballTextureRegion.getHeight(), this.ballTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
ballBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ball, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ball, ballBody, true, true));
scene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);
scene.attachChild(ball);
```

The ball moves in all directions by accelerometer using andEngines IAccelerationListener, What has been tried to restrict the body along x axis, so that it moves only vertically :

In the main game loop, have set x component of its linear velocity as 0 :

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

    public void reset() {
    }

    // main game loop
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        ballBody.setLinearVelocity(0, ballBody.getLinearVelocity().y); // set x velocity as 0
   }
});
```

But now also the ball can move horizontally, its horizontal speed is now lesser but not totally 0. How to restrict its movement along one direction only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the type of box2d body from dynamic to kinematic, read about body types from [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/05/11/understanding-box2d-kinematic-bodies/), and found that in my case kinematic body was better as a dynamic body it was getting affected by all the forces in physical world.

```
ballBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ball, BodyType.KinematicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
```

And set its velocity along y axis like this for vertical movement:

```
penBody.setLinearVelocity(mPhysicsWorld.getGravity().x, 0);
```